# time_zone_select sort selection to display us time zones first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the `Time_zone_select` method rails provides for form builders. This is awesome but I'd like to provide a little better UX. Is it possible to list the US timezones first instead of all the options all combined alphabetically?

```
 <%= form.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, class: "form-input" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `priority_zones` option (second argument, which you are setting as `nil`), which receives an array of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` objects.

For US zones you can use `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones`, for example:

```
<%= form.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, class: "form-input" %>
```

> How can I set a default value?

Just add `default` option, for example:

```
<%= form.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, default: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", class: "form-input" %>
```

You can read more about `time_zone_select` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-time_zone_select).

Comment: Sweet thanks man! Can I ask one more favor? How can I set a default value?

Comment: Sure, just add `default:`, for example: `default: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)`

Comment: @Bitwise Glad to help! Check updated answer for an example using `default`.